# Uncaught ReferenceError: validateProduct is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jsp

I wrote a JS script for a form in a jsp Page.
When I submit the form, console show this: Uncaught ReferenceError: validateProduct is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

JS File has others functions which works, only validateProduct() function doesn't work.

I show you the .js file and just the interested part of .jsp file.

```js
    function css(errore){
    errore.style.textAlign="center";
    errore.style.padding="4% 0 0 2%";
    errore.style.backgroundColor="#fcdde8";
    errore.style.fontFamily="Roboto";
    errore.style.height="35px";
    errore.style.outlineWidth="3px";
    errore.style.outlineColor="#663344";
    errore.style.outlineStyle="solid";
    errore.style.fontSize="15px";
}

$(function(){
    $('#insert').click(
        function(){
        $('#ins').slideToggle('slow');
        });
})

$(function(){
    $('#remove').click(
        function(){
        $('#rem').slideToggle('slow');
        });
})

$(function(){
    $('#modifica').click(
        function(){
        $('#mod').slideToggle('slow');
        });
})

$(function(){
    $('#ordini').click(
        function(){
        $('#scegli1').slideToggle('slow');
        $('#scegli2').slideToggle('slow');
        });
})

$(function(){
    $('#scegli1').click(
        function(){
        $('#oUt').slideToggle('slow');
        });
})

$(function(){
    $('#scegli2').click(
        function(){
        $('#oDate').slideToggle('slow');
        });
})

function validateProduct(){
    var nome=document.getElementById("nome");
    var descrizione=document.getElementById("descrizione");
    var prezzo=document.getElementById("prezzo");
    var errore=document.getElementById("error");
    
    if(nome.value.length<1 || nome.value.length>100){
        css(errore);
        errore.innerHTML="<b>ERRORE:</b>Inserisci nome correttamente!";
        console.log("Sono caduto in errore nome");
        return false;
    }
    
    if(descrizione.value.length>300){
        css(errore);
        errore.innerHTML="<b>ERRORE:</b>Inserisci descrizione correttamente!";
        console.log("Sono caduto in errore descrizione");
        return false;
    }
    
    if(prezzo.value < 0.01){
        css(errore);
        errore.innerHTML="<b>ERRORE:</b>Inserisci prezzo correttamente!";
        console.log("Sono caduto in errore prezzo");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
    <body>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/gestione/gestione.js"></script>
//...
<form action="InserisciProdotto" class=ins id="ins" onSubmit="return validateProduct();">
//...
    </form>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add HTML and make it a [mcve]. Also look in the network tab, perhaps you have a 404 on the js file

Comment: Also you only need to have ONE `var errore = document.getElementById("error");`

Comment: And removed it from inside the function I hope. Anyway, that will not solve your porblem